# System.Threading.Tasks -> Continuations

Tags: c#, .net, task, task-parallel-library

Let's say you have the service:

```
interface ISuessService {
    Task<Thing> Thing1();
    Task<Thing> Thing2(); 
}
```

And I have an extension method `ContinueOnUIThread`, where I can do cool stuff like:

```
myService.Thing1().ContinueOnUIThread(_ => label.Text = "Done!");
```

and interact with the UI thread easily.

What is the best way to implement a new `ContinueWith` extension method that does this:

```
myService.Thing1()
  .ContinueWith(myService.Thing2())
  .ContinueOnUIThread(_ => label.Text = "Done!");
```

Basically starts `Thing2` after `Thing1` is complete, followed by a call to the UI thread.

The closest I've come is something like this, but I really don't like calling `Wait`:

```
myService.Thing1()
  .ContinueWith(_ => { 
     var thing2 = myService.Thing2().Wait(); 
     return thing2.Result; 
   })
  .ContinueOnUIThread(_ => label.Text = "Done!");
```

Is there a clean way to do this?

PS - I don't have .Net 4.5 so no await/async allowed - this code has to run on MonoTouch/Mono for Android so stick to 4.0

PS - note my use of `_`, this is just a shortcut for "I'm not really using this parameter"

Comment: I would just use a plain `ContinueWith` with the synchronization context overload and give it the synchronization context from the UI thread.

Comment: I don't get it: You can pass the synchronization context to the continuation already, so what's the problem?

Comment: `Thing2` doesn't need the UI thread, it should run in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you might be looking for is the [Unwrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780917.aspx) method from [System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.aspx)

```
myService.Thing1()
.ContinueWith(_ => myService.Thing2()).Unwrap()
.ContinueOnUIThread(_ => label.Text = "Done!");
```